# Four GPU's versus two GPU's

Tags: rendering

I'm asking this theoretical question because obviously I haven't tried it. Is 4 GPU's of 4 GB better than 2 GPU's of 8GB specifically for Blender rendering in Cycles since the app allocates a tile to each GPU in the process? Did anyone experimented or knows which combination is faster given that the motheboard, CPU and memory can handle both of them? TY

Answer (score 1):

"Better" is not the question... it is the wrong word to use, as it depends.

4 GPUs will render 4 tiles simultaneously so rendering an image will be faster than with 2.

Memory: GPUs cannot share vRAM, once you hit the limit the GPU will fail.

So it all depends on the complexity of the scene you are trying to render, or how long can you wait for the render to be done.

Comment: Let's say I have a scene with 10mil vertices in it. Can four 4GB gpu's render faster than two 8GB gpu's?

Comment: It is not the number of vertices only, there are multiple factors that determine the resources needed to render an image: modifiers, volumetrics, particles, simulations, size of images used as textures, complexity of materials, number of samples, bounces, render size, denoising, to name a few.

Comment: So what would be the limit for a 4GB gpu in your opinion? There has to be a some factor to determine the complexity of a scene all together. How can I narrow down the complexity and come up with a rough estimation of what VRAm  is needed?

Comment: Test, test, test...

Comment: Depends on a lot of factors including which GPU models you are considering. If you compare 4 low end graphics cards the may end up being slower then only two high end. Scene complexity has a huge role too, some may benefit more from 4 independent cards, other may require more memory, so this question is not really answerable as it stands.

Comment: The idea was that someone could save a lot of money going 4 cards high quality Gtx 1060 6GB each instead of 2 cards RTX 2080 Ti for example, given the cost of them right now. And I'm talking especially for use in Blender not video games or other 3d softwares because they are all different and require different things.

Comment: Speculative questions and hardware recommendations are hard to fit within the format of this site as they generate discussions and opinions. A forum format or social media work better for that. Try blenderartists.org

Comment: I just want to clarify this question. 4 GPU's GTX 1050ti of 4 GB each are not faster than 2 GPU's RTX 2070 of 8GB each. They are almost 25% slower even overclocked with simple scenes. A lot worse doing in complicated scenes. No need to experiment it.

Comment: Ultimately it's all about clock and memory speed of the card. The ones with more VRam run at higher frequencies hence the outcome in rendering.